# TypeError with BeautifulSoup? Or is Multithreading causing it?

Tags: python, multithreading, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a list of up to 60 URLs. For each URL I create a thread. Each thread requests a URL and selects the keywords in the meta if they are provided. All threads write the keywords into the variable data.

I tried to simplify the code as much as possible, but i wanted to also provide my multithreading in case that is causing the error. The traceback says this:

```
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Programming\saas\flask\routes.py", line 724, in run
    worker(url)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Programming\saas\flask\routes.py", line 737, in worker
            keywords1 = soup.find("meta", {"name":"keywords"})['content']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
<meta content="Metallzuschnitt, Kunststoffzuschnitt, Blechzuschnitt, Metallkonfigurator, ProKilo" name="keywords"/>
Metallzuschnitt, Kunststoffzuschnitt, Blechzuschnitt, Metallkonfigurator, ProKilo
```

Notice how it says TypeError, but then still prints the keywords from the meta selected. But why doesn't it write to data?
This is my code:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

mutex = Lock()

threads = []
data = []
websitelist = ['http://www.wilmsmetall.de/', 'https://www.prokilo.de/maerkte/koeln-muelheim/', 'http://www.droesser.de/']

class ReqThread (Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, u_list):                                
        Thread.__init__(self) 
        self.threadID = threadID 
        self.urllist = u_list

    def run(self): 
        print ("Starting %s" % self.threadID)
        for url in self.urllist:
            worker(url)
        print ("Exiting %s" % self.threadID) 

def worker(url):
    global data
    html = requests.get(url, timeout=3)
    html_page = html.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
    keywords1 = soup.find("meta", {"name":"keywords"})['content']
    print(keywords1)
    if keywords1 is not None:
        for keyword in keywords1.split(','):
            mutex.acquire() 
            data.append(keyword.strip())
            mutex.release()

for index, website in enumerate(websitelist):
    website = [website]
    t = ReqThread(index, website)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
for thread in threads:
    thread.join(5)

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it didn't caused by multithreading.

> the cause of raising error:

From the debugger,Only page 'https://www.prokilo.de/maerkte/koeln-muelheim/' could work normally.
Maybe you need to change the code in `soup.find()` when search it other page.
[image]
[image]
[image]

> How to print the right data list?

Maybe an easy way is to add `print(data)` in the `run(self)` function.BTW,in your code:

```
for thread in threads:
    thread.join(5)
```

makes no effects.Because thread has been started.You need to use(If you really need it):

```
t = ReqThread(index, website)
t.start()
t.join() # block the thread.
```

Comment: To add to this answer, you're seeing that printout because your code is parallelized, so the one website which does find the element you're looking for prints out its own result, but the other two are failing, causing the error you're encountering

Comment: @awarrier99 Thanks for suggestion,but he use mutilthread not async.

Comment: Yup I had just realized that, which is why I changed it to "parallelized", but it is still the reason for why some data is being printed, while there are errors as well, rather than what OP was suggesting about it finding the keywords but not "writing to data"